# Atom installation error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, atom-editor

I was getting this error when trying to install Atom using the installer.

[image]

I tried to run as Administrator but ever having the same error.
So I opened the Setup Log and found this line in many places of the log:

```
Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\slack\packages\RELEASES'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this problem, I simply tried to change the AppData folder properties, unchecking the Attribute "Read-Only" and applying to subfolders.

After that, I could install the application and everything is working well.

I don't know whether what I did was the best solution, but it fixed my problem :)

Hope this help someone

Comment: It work's, after trying so many times it only works when i did this solutions, Thanks @rochasdv

Answer (score 2):

If you have anti-virus installed on your system. Please disable it and try it once. Hope this will work for you because this worked for me like a charm.

One more thing you can check that your windows update service is also running. You check it out in Task Manager ->[image: Here is the image of windows service is running]

So do this thing and check it out.

Comment: That was the solution for me! The Windows Updateservice was not running

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission related issue. Could be you don't have permission to write, in that case run as Administrator.

```
Right Click on the installer and select Run As Administrator.
```

If you still have the issue, **disable** your **antivirus, defender or whatever you have** to protect your PC from threats. Once Installed Enable it BACK

Comment: thank you for your answer but I already fix it changing the AppData folder properties, unchecking the Attribute "Read-Only" and applying to subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

if you have Dropbox opened, close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. open control panel
2. Windows firewall
3. click allow an app or feature through  windows firewall
4. In that at right bottom click allow another app
5. Browse the downloaded atom.exe file and click open and click ok

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall or disable the antivirus. In my case Guardian net secure was handling all the things of windows firewall. so i was  not able to allow the app through windows firewall. therefore, it is necessary to uninstall these. then restart your laptop.
after restarting open control panel. go to windows firewall. on left top you will see
allow an app or feature through windows firewall . click on it. dialog box appears. click on change settings. at bottom click allow another app. then browse the downloaded file atom.exe. then install it

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was closing Slack and terminating any of it's processes in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me (Windows 11):

Go to properties>compatability on the installation file. Run the troubleshooter for compatibility, and it shoul provide a solution, wait, and if it works, select that it did so, and you’re all done.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, I simply tried to change the AppData folder properties, unchecking the Attribute "Read-Only" and applying to subfolders.

After that, I could install the application and everything is working well.

This worked for me on Windows 11 home version.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I managed to install by finding an older version.